# How to show 2 instances of the user profile form, displaying different form modes, on the same page?

Tags: 8, forms

I would like to show 2 instances of the User Profile edit form on the same page.  One form mode only shows the username/password widget with the submit button.  The other form mode only shows the contact information with the submit button.

When I try the following, I get `Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException: The "user" entity type did not specify a "user.change_password" form class`.  Note that I've changed the form class to `change_password` as well.

```
$user = User::loadMultiple([$this->account->id()]);
$form = $this->entityFormBuilder->getForm($user[$this->account->id(), 'change_password']
```

I asked a [similar question regarding custom entities](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228490/how-to-display-a-specific-form-mode-in-a-programmatically-displayed-form) but using that solution would require modifying core files.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to modify core files, you can modify the "user" entity type in a hook. This is how you add a form class for the form operation `change_password`:

*mymodule.module*

```
function mymodule_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['user']->setFormClass('change_password', 'Drupal\user\ProfileForm');
}
```